# Zend_Table remove quotes

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

So here it is:

`....AND (c.user_id NOT IN ('2,1'))` So I want to remove the quotes from `NOT IN (2,1)`

```
->where("c.user_id NOT IN (?)",$not_in)
```

Is there a way to get an output like this? `NOT IN (2,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Solved like this:

```
->where("c.user_id NOT IN (?)",new Zend_Db_Expr($exclude))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array, not a string

```
->where("c.user_id NOT IN (?)", $not_in_array)
```

if you only have a string - `explode()` it:

```
$not_in_array = explode(',', $not_in);
```

Comment: @Uffo: http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.12.3/tests/Zend/Db/Select/TestCommon.php ctrl+f for `_selectWhereArray` test PS: "doesn't work" isn't an issue explanation

Comment: @Uffo: that's actually a good case when "tests as documentation" statement works